# View hidden pages in different pagetrees

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have two pagetrees in a TYPO3 (6.2) with different Domain records.
Tree A is the tree where we log into the backend.

When the editor tries to view a hidden page in tree B, he always get a 404 (and not the preview-mode).

I think this is because of the cookie mismatch between be and fe.

How can i configure the backend that the editor can preview all hidden pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically not possible and your guess is correct. Possible solutions are:

- Log in at this domain as well
- Use "hide in menu" instead of "hidden". Please be aware that the page is then available for everyone